# Are windows server 2008 and 2012 compatible?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, compatibility, windows-server-2012

I have domain server that runs with Windows Server 2008. I am trying to join this domain with computer where I have Windows Server 2012 installed. I can recognize the domain, I am offered with authentication dialog, but no matter which of our administrator accounts I log in with, I get wrong username or password error. After about hundred attempts I would say typos are out of question here, and from our other computers running normal windows 7 or XP I had no problems to join this domain.

My question is, does anyone know any compatibility issues that would prevent win server 2012 to join domain of win server 2008? It is a longshot, but I feel like I have tried almost everything else :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could be DNS issue - try to use domain / DC FQDN instead of short name. Also verify that there are no connectivity issues between DC and machine you trying to join.

Windows Server 2012 computers can join a Windows AD domain running at the Windows 2003 or higher domain and forest functionality level - so you may need to verify this.

And starting from Server 2008 R2 there is offline domain join feature - you can try to leverage it & see if it helps in your case.

Comment: thanks for input. Connectivity issues are out of question, ping to domain server works ok, I can also connect with remote desktop from win 2012 server machine. Also, if it would be a connectivity issue, I wouldn't have got as far as the dialog demanding credentials to join the domain (Domain is found)